# Best way to performance monitor for Web services

Tags: web-services, performancecounter, performance

I would like to monitor web services. I would like to see which methods got called the most and number of bytes sent from a web services. The service is hosted on IIS 7. are there any performance counters for that? our services are WCF based web services.

Answer (score 0):

An easy option is to use Appabric Monitoring.
You will have a complete dashboard including calls ratio and duration.

You can also use WCF built-in performance counters such as Operation counters. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731052.aspx)

Comment: can you please give me more info or link on how to use the appfabric monitoring?

Comment: after a quick google search, I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677276.aspx and http://blogs.technet.com/b/appfabric/archive/2010/01/20/monitoring-applications-using-windows-server-appfabric.aspx